# Data analysis: Investigating whether a policy is implemented or not

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, panel-data

Consider a dataset consisting of student wait times for a large number of experts for two periods. Between the two periods,the school may have altered experts’ capacities based on observations of their wait times in the first period. 
what is an empirical approach to test whether the school is indeed using such a strategy.
In fact I need an approach which makes me able to see whether the policy (i.e. increasing experts' capacities) is implemented or not.

PS: Increasing experts' capacities can lead to reduced wait times

Comment: Please describe the data in more detail and explain how "capacities" might be related to "wait times," whatever those phrases might mean.

Comment: The Mann-Whitney  U test would be a default test for comparing significance of difference of unknown distributions of [values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)  for  unpaired data. Any significant difference would be explained by some most plausible hypothesis that the test would not identify  by  itself.

Comment: Increasing capacities can lead to reduced wait times

Comment: Any suggestion?